# "Uncache" a resource

Tags: http, caching, etag

Using the browser cache offers the big advantage of saving a lot of traffic and making your site faster. However, the big disadvantage is that cached resources cannot be "uncached", until they expire and the browser requests the resources again. Or can they?

Is there a way to explicitly tell the browser (in a seperate request or JavaScript, etc.) to uncache a certain resource?

I know of appending version strings like `image.jpg?12342`, but I'm looking for a more elegant alternative.
E-Tags are a cool thing, but they don't really cache. We may save sending the actual resource payload, but the browser still does a request.

Comment: You can ask browser not to cache the contents by sending relevant headers.

Comment: It is not my goal to disable caching. I *do* want to to use the browser cache. It just happens, that from time to time I need to update some resources, like scripts. I then want the browser to immediately download the updated ressources, instead of waiting for the expiration date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out a cache manifest especially if you don't have access to the server.

Yes it is primarily used to "cache" files for using web apps offline however, you can also expliticly declare certain URI's to be non-cached and even versioning your cache manifest will trigger a reload of noted URI's.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Version x 

NETWORK:
uri-path.here
```

http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/

Comment: If you do have access to the server, I believe you could just use mod_expires to control caching per URI or even file types.

Comment: Not a real answer to this question, but that's as close as we can get with the current set of technologies. Could you please add, that changing the manifest (e.g. changing the version comment) will trigger a complete refresh of all resources?